# Sonar-web-frontend-helloworld execution error

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am running the hello world example

I generate the reports but when i come to run the sonar scan i get the very unhelpful exception of

```
-----------
09:42:56.279 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 is not a valid line for a file
        at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument
(Preconditions.java:145)

[![Error description][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the plugin that you use - https://github.com/groupe-sii/sonar-web-frontend-plugin
SonarQube API clearly states that first line in a file has number `1`, but plugin passes `0`.